# Is this exponentation or bitwise XOR

Tags: srp

I'm reading about SRP from [this page](http://srp.stanford.edu/ndss.html) and came accross the line that says a party computes

> v = g^x

I am unfamiliar with reading cryptography texts. Does this mean *g<sup>x</sup>*, or *g ⊕ x*?

Comment: Exponentiation. `^` meaning XOR is something common in C-like languages, but not in Math AFAIK.

Answer (score 5):

In SRP, v = g^x means $v = g^x \mod p$, i.e. exponentiation modulo a large prime $p$.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context, but later in this paper, the author makes it clear that he is using it to mean exponentiation:

> The ``one-way'' verifier-generator P() becomes a modular
>   exponentiation in GF(n):
>
> P(x) = g^x